# XmlHttpRequest onload `this` property

Tags: javascript

Given the code below, `this` inside the `_onChunkComplete` method is the XHR request. Which makes sense. Is there a way to get it to be the actual `Uploader` object?

```
   function Uploader(file, options) {    
        // ... code here ....
        this.upload_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.upload_request.onload =  this._onChunkComplete;
    }

    Uploader.prototype = {
        // ... code here ...
        _onChunkComplete: function() {
            if (this.range_end === this.file_size) {
                console.log('done');
                return;
            }
            this.range_start = this.range_end;
            this.range_end = this.range_start + this.chunk_size;
            if (!this.is_paused) {
                this._upload();
            }
        }
        // ... mode code here...
    };

    var test = new Uploader(formFile, {});
    test.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```js
this.upload_request.onload = this._onChunkComplete.bind(Uploader)
```

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Comment: How did I not know about this...

I did `.bind(this)` and it works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `Uploader` object to the function by parameter:

```
Uploader.prototype = {
    // ... code here ...

    var uploader = this;

    _onChunkComplete: function(uploader) {

        // you can use uploader now

        if (this.range_end === this.file_size) {
            console.log('done');
            return;
        }
        this.range_start = this.range_end;
        this.range_end = this.range_start + this.chunk_size;
        if (!this.is_paused) {
            this._upload();
        }
    }
    // ... mode code here...
};
```

But if you want to override `this` by `uploader` object, Martriay's answer is just right.